# Can the UX.SE logo be used in answers?

Tags: discussion

I've [used the UX.SE logo in an image](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15728/at-what-point-in-the-development-process-should-ux-come-into-play-in-an-agile-wo) to explain where a UX designer would fit in a Scrum workflow.

I wonder if the use is permitted or even fitting? It gives a strong branding —advertising?— sensation, which I see fitting in the SE context and to give some publicity if the image is shared, but it may be counterindicated (can't see how).

Comment: I'm not sure why the ux.se logo was used here - it symbolizes ux.se (not intended presumably) - as opposed to a generic ux designer...?

Comment: @NaoiseGolden It confused me at first, thinking that you using the UX logo to represent ux.se. It does look nice, but it's a bit confusing. It almost seemed like you were trying to say "this is how ux.se does it."

Comment: yeah... well I used it (to represent **all** UX designers) because I liked it and to give some publicity to the site in case someone grabs the image... but those are my concerns you are mentioning.

Comment: I agree with the others that the UX.se logo represents this site,but not UX as a whole. It's especially confusing that you're using it while on the UX.se site. I can see the UX.se logo being used elsewhere, e.g. blog post, other UX forum discussions as a source of the answer(from UX.se). I've seen people do this with the Stack Overflow logo before, which was OK.

Answer (score 2):

So I finally changed it. As @RogerAttrill and @MattRockwell point out, it was confusing. I will put both here just for reference.

Before:

[image: The role of UX in Scrum]

After:

[image: The role of UX in Scrum]